problemDetail.type.org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException 415
Can anyone help me with the below mentioned issue:
@PostMapping(value = AppConstants.SEND_EMAIL+WITH_ATTACHMENT, consumes = { MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE })
@Respo

nseStatus(NO_CONTENT)
    @PostApiResponse
    public ResponseEntity<?> sendEmail(@RequestPart(required = false) MultipartFile file,
                                       @RequestPart @Valid  @RequestBody EmailRequest metadata);

Getting the below error
{
  "type": "problemDetail.type.org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException",
  "title": "problemDetail.title.org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException",
  "status": 415,
  "detail": "problemDetail.org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException",
  "instance": "/api/v2/emailwithattachment",
  "properties": null
}

